# Subsampling without replacement in R

Tags: r, random, sample

There's a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385099/random-subsampling-in-r) to mine on stack, but that doesn't directly answer my question.

I have abundance data for 250 species across 1000 sites. Species are columns, sites are rows. My `abundances` data look something like the data in the linked post above.

```
0    0    3    0    0    201  0    0    0    82
0    23   5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
9    0    0    0    0    12   0    0    0    913
0    7    91   0    8    0    0    92   9    0
131  12   0    410  0    0    0    3    0    0
```

If I wanted to sample 50 individuals from each site, without replacement, how can I do this?
Focusing on code for single sites for now.

This code:
`samples <- sample(1:ncol(abundances), 50, rep=FALSE, prob=abundances[1,])` doesn't work unless I change to `rep=TRUE`. However, I need sampling WITHOUT replacement.

I don't want to use `sample(abundances[1,], 50, rep=FALSE)` because then instead of sampling individuals, it samples species and will report the whole value in that row (i.e. species 6 may occur 201 times at site 1, it'll report 201, rather than 1 individual from that species, resulting in >50 individuals in final subsample).

I essentially want an output identical to what user Dinre answered in post above, but without it being for bootstrapping. I just want to sample without replacement. This process will ultimately be integrated into a for loop for a subsample from each site.

Comment: What should happen if there are fewer than 50 individuals in a site? e.g. row 2

Comment: The total population size at a site is almost always >1 million. The example data are a very, very simplified version of the larger numbers I am actually dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to sample vector elements from each row with the sum of each sampled row equal to a chosen integer, the `size`. In the code below, `n <- 5` is passed as function argument `size`. The call to `runif` adds an element of randomness to the sampling function.

```
fun <- function(x, size){
  x <- x*runif(length(x))
  y <- size*x/sum(x)
  round(y)
}

set.seed(2021)
n <- 5
t(apply(df1, 1, fun, size = n))
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#[1,]  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0   2
#[2,]  0  4  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#[3,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   5
#[4,]  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
#[5,]  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

---

### Data

Here is the question's data in `dput` format.

```
X <-
structure(c(0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 131L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 
0L, 91L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 410L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 201L, 
0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 92L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 82L, 0L, 913L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10")))
```

Comment: I'm not trying to return vector elements. For example, in your example output, row 1 has "201", but your sample size is 5. 

What I'd want is, if I'm sampling 5 from row (site) 1, then the output would be something like:
`0    0    1    0    0     3     0    0    0    1`,
where it's only sampling from individuals that are there, and sampling proportional to abundances (where more abundant individuals are more likely to be sampled), and the output still corresponds to each species is a column and each row is a site.

Comment: @ktg See if after the edit, the code does what you need.